# Linux bonding add new port

Tags: linux, bonding, lacp, lag

I got active bond with two ports on server, under Ubuntu 22.04

Bond mode is: 802.3ad
I want to add one more port.
So, the question, there will be some downtime, bond flapping when I add one more port and apply it via netplan?